# Player or plugin that can transcribe audio to real time subtitles

Tags: video, mplayer, plugin, video-subtitles

I'm searching for a Linux player (or a plugin for an existent player) with a similar functionality to Youtube: transcribe the audio to real time subtitles.

I would like this to help me watch videos on foreign languages.

If the player/plugin can translate too, that would be nice, but, just transcribe will work to me.

Is there one?

My favorite player is SMPlayer, so a solution using it is preferable to me.

Comment: You mean you want speech recognition? That's still difficult, even in controller environments. Are you prepared to pay? It's usually possible to find subtitles for movies…

Comment: Well, depending of the cost, yes. But, isnt't subtitles for common movies, but help to watch video tutorials, for example watch a movie teaching how develop in Django.

Comment: @GarouDan did you find a solution?

Comment: Well, I've heard that the Dragon Naturally Speaking could do this. But I didn't try. If you have advance please let me know